# How do you prove that a set is not freely generated?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, recursion

Let's say we define the set of “babble-strings” inductively as follows:

- “ba” is a babble-string;
- if s is a babble-string, so is “ab”⌢s;
- if s and t are babble-strings, so is s⌢t

Let us call this set *C*. How would one prove that *C* is not freely generated?

Thanks!